# Azure Kusto Data Explorer - convert duration to days

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Is there a way to find number of days from timespan?

For example, 
time(00:00:00.2000000), time(00:30:30), time(01:00:00), time(413.00:00:00)
should return 0, 0, 0, 413

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use format_timespan():

```
let getDays = (t:timespan)
{ 
    toint(format_timespan(t, 'd'))
};
print result = getDays(time(00:00:00.2000000)), //0
               getDays(time(00:30:30)), //0
               getDays(time(01:00:00)), //0
               getDays(time(413.00:00:00)) //413
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way would be to divide the timespan by the a day, for example:

```
datatable(t:timespan) [ time(00:00:00.2000000), time(00:30:30), time(01:00:00), time(413.00:00:00)]
| extend Days = tolong(t/1d)
```